# Run function in the background in mysql using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I have a function in phpmyadmin for split_str, is it possible to run this function in the background?

This is the function i'm using

```
  RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
  LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
  delim, ',')
```

What I'd like to happen is when a new row is added on table1, it will automatically run the function and then maybe do a Select Into and then insert the values on table2.

Is that possible? If it is, how can i do this?

Thank You

Comment: i guess you need php functions for that

Comment: take a look at mysql `triggers`.  They allow you to perform an action on an event, such as a row insert.  Alternatively, use a stored procedure (my personal preference) to take in your data, do the things, and then store the resulting data